# React Dom is covering the entire page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I created a code to display the colors inside of an array, "d", and it's working quite fine. I used document.getElementById to display the colors.

Here's the problem:
The only thing displaying on screen is the list of colors. I created like four divs with different colours to use for something else but that isn't showing again.

If I remove the imported react dom and the getElementById code, all my **blueDv**, **PinkDv** div etc., come back up.

Is there a way to display the result of the array and still show the divs?
Where am I getting it wrong? Why is the document.getElementById covering the entire page?

```
import React from "react";
import REACTDOM from "react-dom";
import "./JsShuffle.css";



const JsShuffle = () => {

    let d = ['Blue', 'pink', 'green', 'yellow'];
    REACTDOM.render(d, document.getElementById('root'));

     return ( 
        <div className= "jsshuffle">
            <div className= "blueDv">
            </div>
            <div className= "pinkDv">
            </div>
            <div className= "greenDv">
            </div>
            <div className= "yellowDv">
            <div id="root"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
        
    );
}

export default JsShuffle;
```

Comment: "I'm trying to use document.getElementById to write some words on my app" — How? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: You are trying to access `#root` which still is not in DOM as your are returning it from the method itself. Overall the code is not making sense  to me .. Could you please share some more context

Comment: @Quentin, I mean I'm trying to display it on the screen. I want to display the array on the screen, and it's actually working. It's just that the entire page is showing only that while the div are nowhere in sight.

Comment: @DiwakarSingh
OK. Let me explain the code.

I created an array, d, listing some random colors. 

After that, I create an empty div id so that I can use document.getElementById to display the array on the screen.

That's what the code does. Its working quite alright. But it's the only thing showing. 

The divs I created for another stuff entirely aren't showing at all. It's like they vanished. When I delete the getElement and REACTDOM I imported, the divs come right back. 

The divs I'm talking about are the BlueDv etc.

Comment: Why you need react here? Your use case is very simple. You can directly do that... Why React?

Comment: @DiwakarSingh 
Please, I don't understand. What do you mean by why I'm using react?

Comment: I mean you just want to show the texts inside array and you are using following libs:-
```
import React from "react";
import REACTDOM from "react-dom";
```
What is the benefit you are getting out of it?

Comment: Oh, I understand you now. I'm actually coding in react. The import react stuff makes everything work.